# Cloning Existing Rows into Same Table using continue id(not null)

Tags: mysql, sql, clone, rows

Mysql, How do I clone existing rows into same table with continue id(not null).
Example table like this.

Fruit : -

```
----------------------------------
id |   name  |    color |   cc   |
----------------------------------
1  |  Apple  |   red    |   111  |
2  |  Banano |   yellow |   111  |
3  |  Melon  |   Green  |   111  |
```

to new (same table):-

Fruit : -

```
----------------------------------
id |   name  |   color  |   cc   |
----------------------------------
1  |  Apple  |   red    |   111  |
2  |  Banana |   yellow |   111  |
3  |  Melon  |   Green  |   111  |
4  |  Apple  |   red    |   222  |
5  |  Banana |   yellow |   222  |
6  |  Melon  |   Green  |   222  |
7  |  Apple  |   red    |   333  |
8  |  Banana |   yellow |   333  |
9  |  Melon  |   Green  |   333  |
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming ID is an auto-increment field, then simply

```
INSERT INTO `fruit` (`name`, `color`, `cc`)
SELECT `name`, `color`, '222'
FROM `fruit`;

INSERT INTO `fruit` (`name`, `color`, `cc`)
SELECT `name`, `color`, '333'
FROM `fruit`
WHERE ID <= 3;
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=60c151e3c40302d9d7a3b648a7e700dd

---

If ID is not an auto-increment field (it probably should be!) then

```
INSERT INTO `fruit` (`id`, `name`, `color`, `cc`)
SELECT `id`+3, `name`, `color`, '222'
FROM `fruit`;

INSERT INTO `fruit` (`id`, `name`, `color`, `cc`)
SELECT `id`+6,`name`, `color`, '333'
FROM `fruit`
WHERE ID <= 3;
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a4cf0604267432e4d2e26efdac8b4b19

(assuming that no-one else adds, removes or changes any rows in between these two statements, of course. Use a transaction if that's potentially an issue).

---

N.B. I must point out though that this appears to potentially be creating some redundant data (i.e. repetition of name and color values) - consider whether you actually need some sort of link table to represent the relationship between the fruit what whatever "cc" is.